# Redundant frame and scrollbars on Jekyll code excerpt

Tags: markdown, jekyll, syntax-highlighting

After following the Jekyll Now guide [here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/08/build-blog-jekyll-github-pages/), I made a simple markdown blog post in `_posts` as expected. I find, however, that my C++ hello world example is rendered with *two* frames - each with a vertical and horizontal scroll bar. I would firstly like just one frame; and secondly for that single frame to have no scroll bar (note that the suggestion [here](https://github.com/barryclark/jekyll-now/issues/984) didn't work). This is a screenshot of the relevant part of the blog post via Chrome:

[image]

The markdown script for the page is below.

````
---
layout: post
title: You're up and running!
---

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::cout << "Hello.\n";
  return 0;
}
```
````

Comment: This is a CSS problem. A code repository url can help.

Comment: Thanks. This is the url I forked from: http://www.github.com/barryclark/jekyll-now. My changes are only to add the code block to 2014-3-3-Hello-World.md.

Answer (score 1):

Use `highlight` tag instead :

```
{% highlight cpp %}
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::cout << "Hello.\n";
  return 0;
}
{% endhighlight %}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did notice some posts using that. Is it an extension of markdown?

Comment: This is jekyll tag.

Comment: I see lots of C++ blogs which don't have this problem. [Here](https://github.com/adishavit/adishavit.github.io) for example, where [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adishavit/adishavit.github.io/master/_posts/2018-04-25-Affine-Space-Types.md) appears as [this](http://videocortex.io/2018/Affine-Space-Types). I know it uses a different theme (Jekyll Uno) from the one used above (Jekyll Now), but how can I identify in advance whether a theme supports the markdown syntax I seek (as described in the question)?